# Ruby on rails attachment_field translated label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I have an input field that the browser keeps showing in Portuguese. I really need to make it show in English even if the user is in Brazil. Any help with that?

The code:

```
        <%= f.attachment_field :brand, direct: true, multiple: false, presigned: true, class: 'form-control uploadable' %>
```

In my view:

[image: My view]

Is there a way that I can translate all my `f.attachment_field`?

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have done

```
<div id="yourBtn" onclick="getFile()">Upload Images</div>
  <div id="choose_button" style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
  <%= form.file_field :images, :multiple => true, id: "upfile", :onchange => "sub(this)"%>
  </div> 
   </div>
```

and the css

```
#yourBtn {

    font-family: calibri;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: gold;
  }

#choose_button {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and looks like this

[image]